# JQGrid IE 9 space issue

Tags: jqgrid, internet-explorer-9, jqgrid-asp.net

Hi I am using JQGrid in my application. It is working good IE 8 , chrome and firefox browsers. But in IE 9 I have an issue in the search filter window. In the search filter window, if I try to enter text in the text box it automatically adding space at the bottom of the window for each key stroke. It is below the search filter and above the reset button.

I am using jqgrid version 4.3.1.

Can you please help me resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Have you clicked on the "Compatibility View" icon adjacent of "Refresh" icon on the address bar? If you turn on the compatibility view of older version, it should work temporarily.

Comment: Clicking on the compatibility view has fixed the issue. But as part of the delivery I should be releasing it to client with out any issues. Can you please suggest me if any changes in JavaScript would fix this issue?

Comment: Please just write a meta tag in the header section as follow: <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge"/>

Comment: you can add the Compatible meta in server side scripting if you use PHP or ASP.net.

Comment: And you can add the following code as well: <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge"/>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="en" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
    <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
    <meta http-equiv="expires" content="3600" />
    <meta name="revisit-after" content="2 days" />
    <meta name="robots" content="index,follow" />